# Fix cursor to Input control in sapui5 always

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a requirement where user is required to copy the text to an input every 30 seconds, so that the user wants the cursor to be fixed there, even after clicking or moving somewhere else it should come back to that particular input filed only, so user can paste easily. Please suggest me how can achieve this using SAPUI5.

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of locking the "cursor" or focus to a specific field, i'd suggest you react to the paste event on the document/app

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event